# Check convergence of $f_{n}(x)=x^{n}-x^{2n}=x^{n}(1-x^{n})$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, convergence-divergence

Check convergence of

$f_{n}(x)=x^{n}-x^{2n}$ where $x\in(0,1)$

Please verify my answer, I'm not sure I'm doing it correctly. Thanks in advance!

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268235/uniform-convergence-of-few-sequence-of-functions/268411#268411).

Comment: I don't see an answer to verify. What do you mean?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal No.

Answer (score 1):

Convergence is not uniform.
Let $f(x)=x^n-x^{2n}=x^n(1-x^n)$, then $f'(x)=nx^{n-1}(1-2x^n)$. Maximum of $f$ on $]0,1[$ is found at $x=(\frac{1}{2})^\frac{1}{n}$, and this maximum is $1\over 4$.

However, there is obviously pointwise convergence on $]0,1[$.

Comment: why does maxima being at given point make it non uniform convergence? Would you bother to explain?

Comment: Of course. Uniform convergence means $sup |f_n-f| \rightarrow 0$. How could that happen if $f$ is the null function and for all $\epsilon>0$, there is some $x$ such that $f(x)>\epsilon$ (actually, $f(x)={1\over4}$) ? I comes just from definition of uniform convergence.

Comment: There is a typo in the preceding comment, it's $f_n(x)>\epsilon$

Comment: There is a further typo, it should be $f_n(x_n)\gt\epsilon$.