# uniform convergence of of $f_n(x)=\sin^n (x)$ on $[0,\pi/2)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, uniform-convergence

$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sin^n(x) = 0  \:\:\:\: \forall x\:\in\:[0,\pi/2) \\$

Since the pointwise limit is continuous $\forall x\:\in\:[0,\pi/2) $ therefore by definition of uniform convergence we have :  $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\{\sup_{0\leq x<\pi/2} |f_n(x)-f(x)|\} = \lim_{n\to \infty}\{\sup_{0\leq x<\pi/2}|f_n(x)-0|\}\:\: \:= \lim_{n\to \infty}\{\sup_{0\leq x < \pi/2} |\sin^n(x)|\}\:\: \:=\:\lim_{n\to \infty}1\:\:=\:\:1\\\neq0$$

Thus the function should not be uniformly convergent.But it is uniformly convergent on the given interval. That means the supremum must be $0$ instead of $1.$ But i don't see why that should be the case. Can somebody please help and clarify the doubt.

Comment: Why does your function uniformly convergent on given interval? Is there another reason justifying your claim?

Comment: using the epsilon definition, we can always choose a bigger enough n, for which |f_n(x)-0| < e , since 0<=sin(x)<1 . sorry i am new here. learning latex.

Comment: The sequence is not uniform convergent, you just showed that.

Comment: i was too thinking the same thing, but i read somewhere it is uniformly convergent and have been confused since then. finally posted here...thank you for clarifying...

Comment: Please define "somewhere".

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268235/uniform-convergence-of-few-sequence-of-functions?rq=1