# Prove a uniform or non-uniform convergence of a functional sequence $f_n(x)=\arctan x^{3n} - \arctan x^{2n}$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

given $$f_n(x)=\arctan (x^{3n}) - \arctan (x^{2n}), x\in[0, +\infty)$$ prove uniform or non-uniform convergence on the intervals $$E_1=[0.75,1]; E_2=[1.5,2]$$

I know there's a technique [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/268411/726850), but I do not understand how the intervals are accounted there.

Comment: Are you dealing with $(\arctan x)^{3n}$ or with $\arctan (x^{3n})$?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net edited

Comment: Thanks for the editing. But the way you edited is not helping.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net oops, my fault, now it should be better